# Maximum number of apps icons & pages in folders & total pages on iPhone from iOS 7 thru till 9.0.2?

Tags: ios, applications, folders, icon

Maximum number of apps icons & pages in folders & total pages on iPhone from iOS 7 thru till 9.0.2?

Maximum number of:

- Total Pages on Springboard outside folders
- Total App icons allowed in iOS folders

  - Pages of icons inside each folder
  - App icons per page of iOS folders

For each iOS version from 7 till now on 9.0.2

Please share.

PS: Only other such post I found is [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50049/maximum-number-of-pages-on-ipad-and-maximum-apps-in-a-folder) for an iPad which does not cover the specific quantities & detailed numbers I am asking, nor is it asking for iPhone, nor the change/ shift of these numbers thru iOS versions.

Comment: The only change I'm aware of from iOS 7 to 9 is that iPad folders are now 4x4 in iOS 9, rather than the 3x3 grid of iOS 7 and 8. Are there more changes?

Comment: [This post](http://ipod.about.com/od/usingios4/f/Iphone-Apps-Iphone-Folders.htm) has some data for iOS 7 that you may find useful.

Comment: I was hoping to get clearview on how Apple has changed these numbers from 7 to 9. Thanks though.

Comment: I know—in my first comment, I said that I think the only way these numbers have changed is that iOS 9-running iPads can how have 4x4 grids. That's all, unless you count iPhone screen size changes in that span.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to check this is to install Xcode for free from the App Store and look at each simulator for each device you care to catalog.

I suppose someone could make a reference table or Wikipedia article to document this over time, but I’m not convinced this would be useful for things other than a trivia question.