# Same number of app icons on each page for iPhone and iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, springboard

App icons on my iPhone are 6 rows by 4 columns = 24 per page but iPad has 5 rows by 4 columns plus ‘dock’

Is there a way to have 6 rows by 4 columns on the iPad also?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to customise the number of rows and columns on iOS without a jailbreak.
However, iPadOS 13 brings an additional column of icons to iPad for more apps per page.

Comment: Also, you can install Xcode and look at layouts in the simulator if ours more curious about all the combinations possible. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211945/maximum-number-of-apps-icons-pages-in-folders-total-pages-on-iphone-from-ios